Como mandar un parametro URL en JMeter
Tengo un método en el cual necesito enviar un parámetro tipo URL para consumirlo, el valor de ese parámetro lo tengo guardado en una variable que sale de un método anterior, como lo incluyo en ese request que lo requiere?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
